# Do the same rules apply to negative noninteger factorials?

Tags: proof-verification, factorial

To show: $$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}_0:\binom{2k}{k}=(-4)^k\binom{-0.5}{k}$$

$\underline{Basecase}$

$k=0$
$$\binom{2\cdot 0}{0}=\frac{0!}{0!0!}=1=\frac{(-0.5)!}{(-0.5)!}=1\cdot \frac{(-0.5)!}{0!(-0.5-0)!}=(-4)^0\cdot \binom{-0.5}{0}$$${\huge \checkmark}$

$\underline{Assumption}$

For some $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ the following holds: $$\binom{2k}{k}=(-4)^k\binom{-0.5}{k}$$
Which is equivalent to $$\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}=(-4)^k\cdot \frac{(-0.5)!}{k!(-0.5-k)!}$$
$\underline{Claim}$

For $(k+1)\in\mathbb{N}_0$ the following holds: $$\binom{2(k+1)}{k+1}=(-4)^{k+1}\binom{-0.5}{k+1}$$
$\underline{Step}$

We show that the equality $$\binom{2(k+1)}{k+1}=(-4)^{k+1}\binom{-0.5}{k+1}$$holds.

First we expand it like the assumption: $$\frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!(k+1)!}=(-4)^{k+1}\cdot \frac{(-0.5)!}{(k+1)!(-0.5-k-1)!}$$
$$\iff \frac{(2k)!}{(k)!(k)!}\cdot\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2}=(-4)^{k}\cdot \frac{(-0.5)!}{(k)!(-0.5-k)!}\cdot (-4) \frac{(-0.5-k)}{(k+1)}$$
Now we use our assumption $$\iff \frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2}=(-4) \frac{(-0.5-k)}{(k+1)}$$
$$\iff (2k+1)(2k+2)=(4k+2)(k+1)$$
$$\iff 4k^2+4k+2k+2=4k^2+4k+2k+2$$

Is the following right? $$(-0.5-k-1)!=\frac{(-0.5-k)!}{(-0.5-k)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We typically use the *gamma function* to extend the factorials to all of $\mathbb{C}$; thus including the negatives, as you desire. However, the gamma function is shifted down by 1; that is,

$$\Gamma(k) = (k-1)!$$

for positive integers $k$. The purpose of this function is to satisfy the properties of the factorial, while being a smooth curve. In fact, one of the restrictions that was applied to find the gamma function was the restriction

$$\Gamma(k+1) = k\Gamma(k)$$

Thus, given $k! = \Gamma(k+1)$, we find that

$$k! = \Gamma(k+1)  = (k)\Gamma(k) = k(k-1)!$$

and as such,

$$(k-1)! = \frac{k!}{k}$$

as requested. Note that this holds only for $k \notin \mathbb{Z}_-$.